# Curl Authentication Code Client Secret and Client ID

Tags: http, curl, oauth-2.0

When using a curl request for authentication, I have all the required information such as client ID, client secret, URL and authorization code, but it seems that everytime I send a request I never get the expected result.

```sh
curl -X POST 'https://identity.moneyhub.co.uk/oidc/token' \
  -H 'Authorization: Basic Base64_encode(<client_id>:<client_secret>)'\
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -d 'grant_type=authorization_code&code=example-auth-code&redirect_uri=example-redirect-uri&sub=example-user-id'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
curl -X POST 'https://identity.moneyhub.co.uk/oidc/token' 
-H 'Authorization: Basic Base64_encode(<client_id>:<client_secret>)'
```

Add `-u` instead of `-H`:

```
-u 'Authorization: Basic Base64_encode…
```

Comment: hi i tried this instead:
curl -X POST 'https://identity.moneyhub.co.uk/oidc/token' \
  -u 'Authorization: Basic Base64_encode(2622c8f8-3115-4693-8d79-731bb2b3e8b6:C6706d85-ce3d-4192-bb94-bcee76e1a4cf)'\
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -d 'grant_type=authorization_code&code=DHvefu6kMcJ_SxRj2r~wfnF4CxR&redirect_uri=https://hoddle.app/moneyhub-redirect-page&sub=example-user-id'
but it response with: no client authentication mechanism provided

Answer (score 0):

```
curl  -X POST https://identity.moneyhub.co.uk/oidc/token
-u <YOUR_KEY_ID>:<YOUR_SECRET>
-H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
-d 'grant_type=authorization_code&code=example-auth-code&redirect_uri=example-redirect-uri&sub=example-user-id'
```

Comment: I got client authentication failed

Comment: Maybe your id or secret is wrong. Plz verify

Answer (score 0):

curl https://api.tink.com/v2/income-checks/b5d548463efd45348f69ea229e953567 
-H 'Authorization: Bearer ${YOUR_CLIENT_ACCESS_TOKEN}'